# ValueError('Cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern')

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I am using a regex with Scrapy to parse the data contained within the first Javascript item called 'Datastore.prime' within the following page:

[Link here](http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/3853)
The regex I am using is this:

```
regex = re.compile('DataStore\.prime\(\'standings\', { stageId: \d+ }.*')
        match2 = re.findall(regex, response.body, re.S)
        match3 = str(match2)
        match3 = match3.replace('<a class="w h"', '').replace('<a class="w a"', '').replace('<a class="d h"', '') \
                 .replace('<a class="d a"', '').replace('<a class="l h"', '').replace('<a class="l a"', '') \
                 .replace('title=', '')
        print match3
```

However this is throwing up the error within the title of this post:

```
     raise ValueError('Cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern')
 exceptions.ValueError: Cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern
```

Can anyone see what the issue is?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to place the modifier inside your `re.compile` pattern, also good to use  raw string notation here.

```
regex = re.compile(r"DataStore\.prime\('standings', { stageId: \d+ }.*", re.S)
                                                                         ^^^^
```

Comment: hi again. That worked in the sense that the code no longer errors, however it is not selecting only the output I want now. I was originally just using a regex of regex = r'\[\[.*?\]\]\);', which was returning everything inside two sets of square brackets on the page. what i wanted was only everything inside the FIRST datastore.prime item on the page, which this code was supposed to deliver, but now i am back where i started...

Comment: backslashes for escapes are in the above example but they arent being displayed for some reason

Comment: that now doesn't return anything.

Comment: By the way, this answered your question on why you were getting an error, Stackoverflow is not a code writing service so if you have more trouble with something else then start a new question please.